# Edit rejection with an uninformed reasoning behind it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, rejected-edits

Yesterday, after looking for a solution to a common problem I experience everyday, namely having many shells scattered throughout many tmux sessions, I stumbled upon this question:

[How to merge 4 windows in to 4 evenly spaced panes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428059/tmux-how-to-merge-4-sessions-into-4-evenly-spaced-panes)

The topic of this question indicates, that it's about tmux sessions. As for a definition of a session in this context, the tmux man page states clearly:

> A session is a single collection of pseudo terminals under the management of tmux.
>   Each session has one or more windows linked to it.
>   A window occupies the entire screen and may be split into rectangular panes, each of which is a separate pseudo terminal.

Tmux session is an object that resides on a tmux server, and aggregates windows and panes.

From the question contents and it's accepted answer however, it seems that the author is asking about **merging tmux windows, not sessions**.

The `tmux join-pane` command, that the author said he tried to accomplish his task with, **has nothing to do with tmux session merging.**

The accepted answer to that question gives a simple method of layouting panes throughout the window, which, again, **has nothing to do with tmux session merging.**

[This question is the first link that pops up in Google](https://www.google.pl/search?safe=off&biw=1280&bih=963&sclient=psy-ab&q=tmux+session+definition&btnG=&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=hYpuWOLdIYKqsgG-35nQDA#safe=off&q=tmux+merge+sessions) when researching the above problem.

Whereas the fourth (third on mine, results may vary) link is a link to an issue on GitHub's repository of tmuxomatic, which proposes a feature intended to solve exactly the problem I have to cope with everyday: merge multiple tmux sessions into one.

Frustrated by the turnout of events, [I posted an edit to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14787714), that changed the topic of the question, and improved it here-and-there.

I made a clear comment in that edit, that the original poster confuses a concept of session with a concept of window.

This edit however, was for some reason rejected, on a basis of "deviating from original poster's intent". Which leads me to believe, that the people who reviewed the edit have never actually used tmux, and are also confusing the two concepts.

Who is in the right? Am I missing something? How can I resolve this issue in the future, namely how to prove such edit's correctness, in a face of the complicated nature of information that it could contain?

Comment: 9 seconds actually. you can't assume the reviewer is "uninformed" just because you disagree with them...

Comment: @KevinB I just showed the exact logic behind why my edit was correct. If I can't assume ignorance, then should I assume coordinated vandalism?

Comment: Why **You** think it was correct. Just because others disagree with you doesn't mean it is ignorance or vandalism.

Comment: @JoeW Because there is an exact definition on the topic which states clearly, that the OP misunderstood the concept. It's like arguing that 1+1=6.

Comment: Just because the op misunderstood something doesn't mean you can change it. The misunderstanding can be very useful in solving the problem and when it is changed it can mask the problem.

Comment: Your question can be boiled down to: "The OP asked a question, but used the incorrect term. Is it appropriate to edit the question to use the correct term?" I'd have to say... it depends on the situation. In this case more people decided it was inappropriate.

Comment: @KevinB:  I'm wondering if the people determining its appropriateness were either looking at the entire context of the question or were simply triggered by this major word change.  Not to say that it isn't a giant red flag, but I'd rather look a little deeper befoer I lump this edit in with other, bad-faith edits.

Comment: How is any of this on-topic for Stack Overflow? Is `tmux` a developer tool? I don't see any code, just command lines.

Comment: i mean... i use it, indirectly, while developing, so... kinda?

Comment: @KevinB Then let me ask this: how to improve this question, so that people who are looking for a sollution to an ultra frustrating problem, doesn't bounce of the wrongly worded questions on this website like this one?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Old ghost of pre-Linux-QA stackoverflow maybe?

Comment: I don't think your edit was inappropriate. but, others did. Instead of re-suggesting the edit, your next course of action should probably be leaving a comment. Maybe the op will fix it, and if not, future visitors may see your comment.

Comment: In any case, if the OP was capable of using the wrong term here, surely others are capable of that too, and may find this question/answer pair if it is left as is

Comment: @KevinB It isn't really a "re-suggestion" as it is a cry for a more proffessionally moderated stack overflow. Cthulu wouldn't have enough limbs to count how many times I hit a question like this here and start to pull off my hairs. But ok, I'll do that.

Comment: @KevinB Maybe, but google indexes by the topic, and when it does, people hit a question and leave unsatissfied. So... what's the point?

Comment: Re: downvotes. I didn't downvote, but it may be due to your writing style. Honestly, it comes across more like a rant than anything else.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Forgot to add a ':)' at the end, maybe that's it :). No but seriously I don't mean to. Need to work on that.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik In my opinion, the body of the question doesn't actually sound that rant-y, but the title certainly does.

Comment: @Don'tPanic In that case I don't really care. I don't place subjective opinions high, I'd rather use rigorous logic. But hey, if it hurt someones feelings, then feel free to punch back.

Comment: Not valuing an individual opinion is certainly  understandable, and I'm sure there are others who don't share my opinion, but I only bothered to mention it because of the importance of the title. It really sets the tone for the entire post. (That's also my opinion, but I think that's one that many people _would_ agree with.) A lot of people seem to come to meta just to complain, which isn't very useful, so people may be put off from the post from the beginning if it sounds like it's going to be a rant.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Well yea, I'm guilty of complaining here too. Maybe that's the problem. But still, nobody cared to answer the question. And I don't even care about this particular edit at this point. I just wanted to make the site better, and while there are other people who wan't it to, most of us (them?) care more about profile statistics and trophies than actual quality of information. In that spirit, who am I to tell that somebody made a mistake, cheeky me. There's no way to prove it right now, because people can't differentiate between opinion and logical argument.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I also wonder if somebody will post that edit. I would really love to do it, but then I think I shouldn't after all this. Could you do it? OH WAIT somebody did and it was accepted. So it seems after all, that the 10 downvotes were worth it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes, going down the rabbit hole pays dividends.  With that, I'm leaning more towards this edit being in good-faith rather than changing the meaning.

Let's talk about the question first.  In the question, the OP explicitly references the commands they're using to attempt to accomplish their goal.

That is, they use **`tmux join-pane -h -s PP2 -t PP1`**.  To really grok that, we need to look at the [man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) for tmux.

What we discover:

- `join-pane` itself is just like `split-window` with a few other tricks up its sleeve.
- `split-window` identifies some of the parameters; for completeness, these are:

  - `-h` for a horizontal split
  - `-s` for the source pane
  - `-t` for the target pane

***Nowhere*** in that command cluster did I see "session" mentioned.

I don't claim to be an expert or even that proficient with tmux; I just read the fine manual provided.

With that...I don't think this edit was inappropriate.  But, I could only reach that conclusion ***after*** I had looked the information up and verified it.

The reason that this edit was rejected could be attributed to a few things:

- The reviewers don't know or understand tmux, but do have a relatively okay handle on reviews at Stack Overflow.
- It is the standing convention *not* to allow edits which appear to largely change the meaning of the question.  Words being switched around can do that, and without any deeper checking, appearances can be quite strong to that.
- **There is no real hard-and-fast rule** when it comes to reviews like this.  Not every reviewer is going to either know or take the time to learn about why this change was made, and simply put, your review was put in the hands of reviewers who, while they meant well, simply didn't know.

I'm not going to say that the reviewers were wrong on this - they're doing exactly what they're trained to do - but it does become frustrating when these kinds of scenarios happen.  With that, I do agree with your edit, and I hope that Meta can reach a consensus on it as well (including whether or not it could do with being migrated).

Comment: @yellowantphil I think the idea here is that the edit didn't deviate from the intent, it rather clarified the intent, *while* changing the literal meaning of the written text *to what the author was actually asking about*. In contrast, edits which deviate from the intent are inherently a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

> that changed the topic of the question

Yeah, you can't do that. You can't change the topic of a question for the OP, even if they are confused or using the wrong terms.

You especially can't do that when there are answers on the question. You can edit to make a question clearer but you can't make edits that actually change what's being asked.

> not something that changes the entire meaning
>
> ...
>
> In other words, this edit does not change the meaning of the post.

**It doesn't matter because it will get rejected anyway.**

The OP has under 2K which means their edits are only suggestions until they get reviewed and the reviewers are going to reject anything that even *looks* like it changes the meaning of the question. It does not matter if it is a good change, it's not going to get approved if it looks like it might change the intent of the OP.

I'm not saying the OP shouldn't do anything at all to fix the problem. I'm saying that they can't fix it with a suggested edit.

Comment: So I should just leave the question alone, even if it gets hits from google just because it is named wrong way?

Comment: Slow down here.  There is more to this than the OP simply changing around the topic.  I'm getting the impression that this really was a good-faith edit and not something that changes the entire meaning.  Blanket-term responses aren't helpful in this context; for those of us not entirely well-versed in the ways of Tmux, it's worth the exercise to investigate a little more.

Comment: @Makoto - I never accused the OP of doing something *malicious*, I pointed out that what they did was, based on my understanding of the rules and personal experience with suggested edits, against the rules.

Comment: @BSMP:  Be careful with the blanket application of the rules.  99% of the time it works, but you do have to do a *little* bit of a check to see if it applies in almost every case.  This time it didn't quite add up, so I went a bit deeper.  I'll condense my thoughts into my own answer.

Comment: @BSMP Well, that's the point. I know what the rules state. But that rejection made the whole website lose a bit of it's value. The ergo here is that the stiff interpretation of the rules state: you shouldn't ever edit the topic - even if it is misleading, unhelpful, and confusing.

Comment: Guessing an author's intent can be tricky. But in this case it's not. The author included a MCVE (the `tmux join-pane -h -s PP2 -t PP1` commands) by which we can unambiguously conclude that the OP simply made an error when he typed "session". In other words, this edit does *not* change the meaning of the post. It simply rectifies an error.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thank you. I rest my case.